# Receiving IPN and SSL Secure Channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, paypal

I have a project in MVC. Using IPN to receive notifications of payments made to update the database. The project works fine until I click "Return to ___ Test Store". [image: Return to Store]

I receive the following server error:

[image]

Controller: I followed this example => [PayPal & MVC](http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2012/06/how-to-use-paypal-with-asp-net-mvc/)

```
                if (sAmountPaid != null)
            {
                // look up the requested service using the item_number
                int id = int.Parse(Request["item_number"]);
                var requestedService = db.RequestedServices.Where(rs => rs.RequestedServiceId == id).SingleOrDefault();

                // look up the payment adjustment
                var paymentAdjustment = requestedService.PaymentAdjustments.FirstOrDefault();

                decimal amount = decimal.Parse(Request["mc_gross"]); // pull out the total amount
                string payerEmail = Request["payer_email"]; // and the paypal user email

                // before creating a new payment object, make sure there isn't an item with the transaction id already
                // in the database

                var paymentCheck = db.Payments.Where(p => p.TransactionId == transactionID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (paymentCheck != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Success = "yes";
                    return View();
                }

                // if a payment with that id hasn't been made, create one

                Payment payment = new Payment()
                {
                    DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsCompleted = false,
                    RequestedServiceId = id,
                    TransactionId = transactionID,
                    Amount = amount,
                    Email = payerEmail,
                };

                // set the payment completion status based on the result
                if (Request["payment_status"].ToLower() == "completed")
                {
                    payment.IsCompleted = true;
                    paymentAdjustment.IsCompleted = true;
                }

                db.Payments.Add(payment);
                db.Entry(paymentAdjustment).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                // send an email notifying the contractor that a new service has been requested
                IEmailSender emailsender = new GoDaddyEmailSender(); // send the emails via GoDaddy (implementing IEmailSender interface)

                string subject = "Full Payment Adjustment Completed!";
                string body = null;

                var customer = db.my_aspnet_users.Where(u => u.id == requestedService.UserId).SingleOrDefault();

                var yardladEmail = db.SiteSettings.Where(ss => ss.Name == "Yard Lad Contact Email").Single().Value;

                foreach (var user in requestedService.Contractor.ContractorUsers)
                {
                    var recipientEmail = Membership.GetUser(user.UserId, false).Email;
                    var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.Where(up => up.UserId == user.UserId).SingleOrDefault();

                    body += "<p>A new payment amount for the " + requestedService.ContractorService.Service.Name.ToLower() + " service has been completed!</p>";
                    body += "<p>Login to your account <a href=\"https://www.yardlad.com/Contractor/ServiceHistory/" + requestedService.ContractorId + "\">here</a> to view the changes</p>";

                    // send email to the users (will need to replace the emails when deploying)
                    try
                    {
                        emailsender.SendEmail(subject, body, from: yardladEmail, recipient: recipientEmail);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // log
                    }
                }

                ViewBag.Success = "yes";
                return View();

            }
```

I have tried running the debugger, but when it reaches this portion of my controller nothing is triggered. All other steps and processes before work with no problems.

Comment: Paypal requires **TLS 1.2** - I can't see it in the code you posted but in the stack trace you are making a `HttpWebRequest` (likely to verify the IPN) and that's the _likely_ issue. You have to make sure all your requests to Paypal _specifically_ use TLS 1.2. Hth.